# iOS json: put request with token

Tags: objective-c, json, authentication, token

I have a question concerning json authentication with tokens. I have a server with a database. When I want to POST or PUT to the database I need to have a token with the request, which is unique for every user. I have tried this with a rest client and it works fine. I will attach a print screen of the rest client. But when I want to do it from the app I get the response "Access denied". What am I doing wrong?

Here is my objective-c code:

```
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@\",\"skills\":\"%@\",\"description\":\"%@\",\"expectation\":\"%@\",\"mail\":\"%@\"}",profileName.text,profileSkills.text,profileDescription.text,profileExpectations.text,profileMail.text];

NSString *testToken = @"6ecf0fe735487bcaab74c0fcd3ed57dc";    
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://31.208.72.233:3000/persons/63"];    
NSData *JSONBody = [jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *headerValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Authorization: Token %@" , testToken];
NSMutableURLRequest *loginRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
loginRequest.HTTPMethod = @"PUT";
loginRequest.HTTPBody = JSONBody;
[loginRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[loginRequest addValue:headerValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:loginRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSString *txt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

[image]

Comment: In the headers you have key value pairs. The `Authorization` is the key and everything after is the value. It looks like what you may actually be sending is `Authorization: Authorization: Token 6ecf0fe735487bcaab74c0fcd3ed57dc`. Can you try removing `Authorization` from `headerValue`

Comment: That help I think, now i get the response:
2014-02-16 16:40:51.248 "AppName"[1743:3307] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9800)
2014-02-16 16:40:51.265 "AppName"[1743:3307] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9800)
2014-02-16 16:40:51.290 "AppName"[1743:3307] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9800)
2014-02-16 16:40:51.290 "AppName"[1743:3307] NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9800)

Comment: Does your client give you the full raw request - could you post this

Comment: The actual HTTP request so we can see what the difference is - if the client works but your code doesn't there must be a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the headers you have key value pairs. The `Authorization` is the key part and everything after the `:` is the value.

It looks like what you may actually be sending is `Authorization: Authorization: Token 6ecf0fe735487bcaab74c0fcd3ed57dc`. You should remove `Authorization` from `headerValue`